# Pass array to view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a breadcrumb that i send to my view pages, but the part that have an array not load, just static code.

I think the problem it's in variable inside array, because i have another breadcrumbs with same problem, the static is loaded.

Example breadcrumb that I want: Home -> Product -> "Tshirt name"

Controller:

```
    $itensBreadCrumb["itensBreadCrumb"] = array(
    "Home"                     => "home", 
    "Produtos"                 => "produtos", // after this don't load in view.
    strtolower($produto->nome) => ""
    );

$dataProdutos['produto']    = $produto;
$dataProdutos['estoques']   = $this->produtos_model->retornaEstoqueProduto($produto[0]->id);
$dataProdutos['breadcrumb'] = $this->load->view("breadcrumb", $itensBreadCrumb, TRUE);
```

Breadcrumb structure View:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <?php foreach ($itensBreadCrumb as $item => $link) { 
                if(!empty($link)){  
            ?>
                <a href="<?=$link?>" class="item-bread"><?=$item?></a>                  
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <span class="item-bread"><?=$item?></span>
            <?php
                } 
            } ?>                
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How i'm calling breadcrumb in pages.

```
<?= $breadcrumb ?>
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: As the example above "Example breadcrumb that I want: Home -> Product -> "Tshirt name" my breadcrumb just load "Home -> Product" the variable itensBreadCrumb not pass to view. And I don't know if the problem it's in "<?= $breadcrumb ?> that i call in view" or the way that I create the array.